# Why passing an object pointer to a method, where it is deleted, is different from deleting the object directly?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

The code causing a leak of one block is as follows:

```
    in = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");
    in->close();
    Mem::delObject(in);
```

where `RandomAccessFile` is the class with the `string` field, and `delObject()` is a static method as follows:

```
    void Mem::delObject(Object* object) {
        delete object;
    }
```

The leaked block is that of `string`.

If I replace the method `delObject` with a direct `delete`:

```
    in = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");
    in->close();
    delete(in);
```

the leak is gone. If the method is not replaced, but removed instead:

```
    in = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");
    in->close();
    // Mem::delObject(in);
    // delete(in);
```

there are two leaked blocks. I guess the field and the object that contained it.

So: why these two ways of deleting an object behave differently?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can only guess but it seems you forgot a [virtual destructor](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7) in Object class. Thus the RandomAccessFile destructor won't be called causing a leak of its properties.

Comment: +1; This makes sense, because the pointer accepted in the function signature is `Object` rather than `RandomAccessFile`.

Comment: @dark then why direct `delete` works? Also, the class `Object`, and its subclass `RandomAccessFile`, do not contain any dynamically allocated fields.

Comment: Because you call the direct delete on RandomAccessFile object so the compiler knows what destructor to call. The compiler loses this info when you pass it as Object * to the delObject function. The classes actually do contain dynamically allocated fields - std::string (usually) uses dynamic allocation for its content.

Comment: More precisely - you call delete with a pointer, not an object. So when you `delete in;`, `in` has type `RandomAccessFile*`, so the RandomAccessFile destructor is called. When you `delete object;`, `object` has type `Object*`, and so if the destructor of `Object` is not virtual then behavior is undefined. What appears to actually happen is that the `Object` part of the object is destructed and deleted, but the `RandomAccessFile` part of the object is never destructed, and so the `string` is never destructed and so the dynamically-allocated memory held by the `string` is never freed.

Comment: Thanks! A virtual destructor helped.

Comment: @arataj: The virtual destructor in base class allows the destruction to happen in a phased and orderly manner and the entire object(base as well as derived) gets cleanly destructed. So the rule is **If you are going to call delete on a Base class pointer pointing to dynamically allocated object of derived class then always have a virtual destructor in base class**